# Having trouble pasting array onto blank sheet in Excel with VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, paste

I have written code to generate lots of lines in an array and made some edits from a previous version to try to speed things up and now I am running into problems with the code pasting into the blank page. Below is the applicable code:

```
Dim Results

[Block of code declaring variables to run For Loops]

ReDim Results(1 To 50000, 1 To 9)

'Clear Sheet

Sheets("Generated").Activate
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents

Dim Rw As Single

[Block of For Loops to generate rows in Array]

If Rw = 50000 Then GoTo PasteResults
    Rw = Rw + 1
    'Create Vector Array, Places Player into appropriate column
    Results(Rw, 1) = Range("C2"): Results(Rw, 2) = Range("C3"): Results(Rw, 3) = Range("C4"):
    Results(Rw, 4) = Range("C5"): Results(Rw, 5) = Range("C6"): Results(Rw, 6) = Range("C7"):
    Results(Rw, 7) = Range("C8"): Results(Rw, 8) = Range("C9"): Results(Rw, 9) = Range("C10")
    [Block finishing For Loops]
    PasteResults:
    **Sheets("Generated").Cells(1).Resize(Rw, 9) = Results**
    Sheets("Generated").Activate
```

The second to last line is where I am seeing the error occur when running my code. Any suggestions for what is going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Highly suggest you read [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx). Not sure why you're looping at all to create an array.

Comment: That's the main thing, but also using Select and Goto is not recommended.